# How to set the value If the combobox does not change the value in WPF MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

In my WPF application I have a combo box. It binds data by MVVM design pattern. It works fine.

[image]

In the XAML

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ValetType}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemValet, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

In the ViewModel

```
valetTypes = GetValueForValet();
public ObservableCollection<Valet> ValetType
{
    get { return valetTypes; }
    set { valetTypes = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ValetType"); }
}

public Valet SelectedItemValet
{
    get { return selectedItemValet;}
    set { selectedItemValet = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItemValet"); }
}
```

One of the problems I face is that when I do not change the combo box value it binds null, otherwise it binds. I set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem  as true it tells a Selector should keep the SelectedItem synchronized with the current item. But would not work. How could I do this? I am new to WPF MVVM.

Comment: If you want a default value in your SelectedItemValet you need to set it, either in your ViewModel or in your XAML: in XAML, set SelectedIndex to 0, in cs set selectedItemValet to something

Comment: In your ViewModel, after loading `ValetType`, do something like `this.SelectedItemValet=ValetType.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Comb box does not displays any selected item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You´ve got one problem in your code:

```
public ValetServices SelectedItemValet
{
    get { return selectedItemValet;}
    set { selectedItemValet = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItemValet"); }
}
```

`ValetType` is Type `Valet`, but `SelectedItemValet` is Type `ValetServices`. They should match. After changing that, to select the first item for example, do this:

```
valetTypes = GetValueForValet();
this.SelectedItemValet=ValetType.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It was a mistake by me, It is Valet not ValetService, Its updated.

Comment: Ok..if you put a breakpoint in your SelectedItemValet setter and you select a value in your combo, does it hit the breakpoint? @SanjeevS

Comment: No it does not hit

Comment: Hmm..so ValetType binding its ok but SelectedItem not..check the spelling of `SelectedItemValet` to be exactly the same in your xaml and viemodel. Sometimes a simple letter makes the difference. Also check `selectedItemValet` private variable.In the code you've shown us we can't see the definition.

Comment: when I change the combobox value, It  hits, If I save the value without changing it, not hit, and value is 0

Comment: Ok,so the binding is ok. Did you try what I told you in the second part of my answer? `valetTypes = GetValueForValet();
this.SelectedItemValet=ValetType.FirstOrDefault();` ?

Comment: Cool Yes Its work now, Thanks, I wrongly done in the base constructor  selectedItemValet = new Valet();

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution would be to provide a default value to your `SelectedItemValet`.

In some method of your ViewModel, that is called when you ViewModel is initialized (typically the constructor) you can set `SelectedItemValet` to the value you want